# GCP Vertex AI Training Custom Job : User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm struggling to execute a query with Bigquery python client from inside a training  custom job of Vertex AI from Google Cloud Platform.

I have built a Docker image which contains this python code then I have pushed it to  Container Registry (eu.gcr.io)

I am using this command to deploy

```sh
      gcloud beta ai custom-jobs create --region=europe-west1 --display-name="$job_name" \
        --config=config_custom_container.yaml \
        --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=n1-standard-4,replica-count=1,container-image-uri="$docker_img_path" \
        --args="${model_type},${env},${now}"
```

I have even tried to use the option --service-account to specify a service account with admin Bigquery role, it did not work.

According to this link
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control?hl=th#granting_service_agents_access_to_other_resources

the Google-managed service accounts for AI Platform Custom Code Service Agent (Vertex AI) have already the right to access to BigQuery, so I do not understand why my job fails with this error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/*******/jobs?prettyPrint=false: 
Access Denied: Project *******:
User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project *******.
```

I have replaced the id with *******

---

Edit:
I have tried several configuration, my last config YAML file only contents this

```
baseOutputDirectory:
  outputUriPrefix:
```

Using the field `serviceAccount` does not seem to edit the actual configuration unlike --service-account option

---

**Edit 14-06-2021 :  **Quick Fix****

like @Ricco.D said

> try explicitly defining the project_id in your bigquery code if you
> have not done this yet.

`bigquery.Client(project=[your-project])`

has fixed my problem. I still do not know about the causes.

Comment: Did you define the service account to be used in your yaml file? If possible can you edit your post and show your yaml as well?

Comment: Using the field serviceAccount does not seem to edit the actual configuration unlike --service-account option

I have added my configuration file

Comment: What service accounts did you try using `--service-account`? Like a custom service account, vertex ai default service account, etc.

Comment: I have used a custom service account. I guess if I do not explicitly mention it, it will use the Google-managed service accounts for AI Platform

Comment: Is the BigQuery dataset that you use is created in the same project where you invoke the custom job? To troubleshoot can you try changing the role of the [vertex service agent](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control?hl=th#service-agents) to **Editor** and check if it will work.

Comment: Yes they are both in the same projet. I have edit the vertex service agent, it does not work neither :/

Comment: Can you try explicitly defining the project_id in your bigquery code if you have not done this yet. `bigquery.Client(project=[your-project], credentials=credentials)`?

Comment: well strangely set the project name (project=[your-project]) has fixed the problem, thanks but 
I do not understand why I need to do that

Comment: I will post this as answer, so this fix will be visible to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue it is needed to explicitly specify the project ID in the Bigquery code.

Example:

```
bigquery.Client(project=[your-project], credentials=credentials)
```