# What is the "BigQuery project for exporting data" in Vertex AI Model training

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am following [this guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vertex-ai-custom-code-training#4) in setting up a vertex AI pipeline. I am told to supply the "BigQuery project for exporting data", except that the guide is not clear on what this BigQuery project is. I have tried supplying the name of my GCP Project to no avail.

[Here is the photo of the field needing this BigQuery project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X5Gt.png)

[Here is a photo of the guide that requests this information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZvX3.png)

Comment: Have you tried `Project ID` instead of `Project Name` if both are not same?

Comment: Does the accepted answer to this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67928917/98811